# How do I search by java enums

Tags: elasticsearch

I have data stored in elastic search. One of the fields is logging level. These are defined in Java enum.

The enums are :

```
0 => undefined
1 => info
2 => low
3 => high
4 => fatal
```

EDIT:
This is what I am trying, but keep getting Variable [level] is not defined error.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' "http://localhost:33206/_search" -d'
{
    "sort" : {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "params.mapping[doc['level'].value]",
                "params" : {
                  "UNDEFINED": 0,
                  "INFO": 1,
                  "LOW": 2,
                  "HIGH": 3,
                  "FATAL": 4
                }
            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}

'
```

In elastic search we are storing Strings rather than the number.

If I wanted to query elastic search and have it ordered by the corresponding numbers, how do I do that? Of course sorting by string will produce wrong results.

Comment: Can you add a sample document and did you try `doc['level'].value` without `params.mapping`? `level` is a text here. And add the exact error you are getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My script was correct, except for the single quote around "level". Changing it to double quotes makes it work.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible and not recommended with [scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) as it is not good from performance perspective.

You should have a separate field where you need to store the `integer` value and sort it.

**Reasons not to have scripts:**

> If possible, avoid using scripts or scripted fields in searches.
> Because scripts can’t make use of index structures, using scripts in
> search queries can result in slower search speeds.
>
> If you often use scripts to transform indexed data, you can speed up
> search by making these changes during ingest instead. However, that
> often means slower index speeds.

And one more thing is `security`. There are loopholes which makes it vulnerable.

[Reference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html#_avoid_scripts)

Comment: could you point me something that says why sorting this way using scripts is not good for performance. I am really curious to know how and why.